# Custom font in Corona Labs don't work

Tags: android, fonts, lua, coronasdk, custom-font

So I've read a lot of topics, articles and stuff about it. Most ppl have problem with font don't working on simulator, but I have problem with running it in app on phone. I have Samsung Galaxy Core, font Venice Classic. It's in main folder (with main.lua). I even tried to put it in 'Resources' folders in program files. I have no more ideas...

http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/mainpng_erppqqw.png
http://s4.ifotos.pl/img/simpng_erppqqs.png

Can you help?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681054/how-do-you-integrate-custom-fonts-in-an-app/19688781#19688781 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404858/how-to-add-custom-font-in-corona-for-android/14413840#14413840,

Comment: I did all tha you and others suggested in both threads (and much more befor), but still - it don't work :s As I showed - it work in simulator, it is in main folder. Corona Build - 2013.2100

Comment: Can you post your code..?

Comment: If anyone is reading this: I've changed name to VENICE.ttf and it's working now... No idea what happend.